# Node.js http server: "getifaddres: Too many open files"

Tags: node.js

I'm currently running a nodejs server, and using GazeboJS to connect to the Gazebo server in order to send messages.

The problem is: 
From my searches it seems like its due to the linux open file limit which is default at 1024 (Using Ubunuty 14.04). Most solutions seem to be to increase the open file limit.

However I don't know why my script is opening files and not closing them. It seems like each http request opens a connection which is not closed even though a response is sent? The http requests are coming from a Lua script using [async](https://github.com/clementfarabet/async).

The error

```
getifaddres: Too many open files
```

occurs after exactly 1024 requests.

I have no experience with webservers so I hope someone could give an explanation.

The details of the nodejs server i'm running:

The server is created using

```
http.createServer(function(req, res))
```

when a HTTP GET request is received, the response is sent as a string. Example of one response

```
gazebo.subscribe(obj.states[select].type,  obj.states[select].topic, function(err, msg)   // msg is a JSON object
{
    if (err)
    {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    res.setHeader('Content-Type',  'text/html');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(msg));
    gazebo.unsubscribe(obj.states[select].topic);   
})
```

The script makes use of the publish/subscribe topics in the Gazebo server to extract information or publish actions. More information about Gazebo communication is [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=topics_subscribed).

Comment: Try to ensure `res.end()` is called in all scenarios.

Comment: Chances are you are leaking (e.g. opening, but failing to close) a file/socket handle somewhere in each request.  We'd have to see more of your code to know where.